# Using OpenCV pixel coordinates in OpenGL to draw a square

Tags: opengl, opencv

I have a 4x2 array of 2D vertices generated by OpenCV for a Square marker. I want to use these coordinates in OpenGL coordinate system to draw a 2D Quad in the **exact** location of the marker. How to do this?

Here's my code, as you can see below that the 2D quad is drawn smaller than the marker.

```
// 'CvMat* dstPoints2D' is generated using cvProjectPoints2()
glPushMatrix();      
glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
glVertex2f((float)dstPoints2D->data.fl[2], (float)dstPoints2D->data.fl[3]); // right, bottom
glVertex2f((float)dstPoints2D->data.fl[0], (float)dstPoints2D->data.fl[1]); //Left, bottom
glVertex2f((float)dstPoints2D->data.fl[4], (float)dstPoints2D->data.fl[5]); // left, top      
glVertex2f((float)dstPoints2D->data.fl[6], (float)dstPoints2D->data.fl[7]); // right, top
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post the 4 (x, y) pairs for each rectangle?

Comment: I captured these coordinates at a random moment. These vary each time I move the camera. (x,y) coordinates found in dstPoints2D `(50.8629, 95.2119), (42.4225, 199.088), (161.459, 94.3529), (159.245, 197.341)`

Comment: +1 for your interest. Maybe it's an issue with camera calibration (intrinsic, distortion coeff matrices). My question is this: The above shape has been drawn using glVertex2f (in 2D space of OpenGL). **How to use matrices generates in OpenCV to draw a 3D object and place it in the exact location in OpenGL? **

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're not having the same coordinate system (CS). Your OpenCV vertices are 2D. You'll need to first calibrate the OpenGL CS and second apply a size factor. You would want to do this using only 2 points (extremum points of one of your square sides or diagnoals). Otherwise you'il need a more complex algorithm to fit using all the vertices informations you have (in case your square become something else, e.g., lozenge).

The easy way is to add a translation factor to your OpenGL square CS for the first point + a size factor and the direction :)

I guess your OpenGL scene is in ortho (orthographic) mode and your square remain a square and not a lozenge.